# How to use unicode strings with knitr on windows

Tags: r, knitr

Here's a simple markdown file:

````
---
title: "blah"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(tibble(x=1:2)) +
  aes(x=x, y=x) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(y = "← low      high →")
```
````

Notice the arrows. They show up when running the code via the console to RStudio's plot tab. But for an HTML knit, they don't work:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the unicode instead of the actual character:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(tibble(x=1:2)) +
  aes(x=x, y=x) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(y = "\u2190 low      high \u2192")
```

[image]